# How does handler work? Why does my animation's speed double after i restart activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler

So I found an example online and I used the handler they created for the snake game i created. However when I go from the main page to the gameview then i click back on the android tablet and start my game view again, the speed of my animation seem to doubled.
This is the handler.

```
class RefreshHandler extends Handler { //Makes animation possible
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Snake.this.update();
            Snake.gamePanel.invalidate();
        }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
}
```

This is my update function that is called during oncreate of my game activity;

```
private void update() {
    //contains some code borrowed from snake example
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentTime - lastUpdateTime >= delay) {
        if (!gamePaused) {
            gamePanel.invalidate();
            lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
        }
    }
    refreshHandler.sleep(delay);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //remove the title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //fullscreen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //Set top and left boundaries; ball tends to get stuck on these
    //set up the application context for toast notifications
    context = getApplicationContext();
    gamePanel = new GameView(this);
    drawColor.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    up=true;
    setContentView(gamePanel);
    lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove all handler message in onPause and start in onResume.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html